# How to simply this using K map

Tags: boolean, digital, karnaugh-map

Simplify the following function using K map:

```
1). Y=(A+B)(A+C') (A'+B')(A'+C)
2). Y=C'D'+ABC'+AB'D'+ABD'+A'B'D' 
3). Y=П M (0,1,4,5,6,8,9,12,13,14)
```

I want the solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here are the simplified expressions for each function using Karnaugh maps:

```
 1) Y = (A+B)(A+C’) (A’+B’)(A’+C) = A + BC’
 2) Y = C’D’+ABC’+AB’D’+ABD’+A’B’D’ = C’D’ + AB
 3) Y = ΠM(0,1,4,5,6,8,9,12,13,14) = Σm(2,3,7,10,11,15) = A’B’C + A’BC’ + AB’C’ + ABC
```